# Crash on updating appcompat to 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.feelinginhell.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        >

        <Button
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button6" />

        <Button
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button7" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It was working fine before updating the appcompat. Now I am getting this Exception :

```
03-09 05:35:37.015 31401-31401/com.feelinginhell E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.feelinginhell/com.feelinginhell.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class Button
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class Button
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
at com.feelinginhell.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
```

But If I remove  this line >> `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"` 
it works fine.This style was working on using an earlier version of appcompat. Need Help

Comment: what is at line *MainActivity.java:11* ?

Comment: can you post build.gradle of app here? the problem might be build tool version in build.gradle file.

Comment: there is some problem with your style

Comment: @Vivek I used the same style with appcompat 22.1.+ and it worked

Comment: @gvsharma  my project's build.gradle file is very basic. I don't suspect any problem there.

Comment: @krishan -- Having the same issue with button styles when updating to 23.2.0. Seemed to be resolved when moving to 23.2.1.